# Azure.Cosmos or Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos, Azure.Storage.Blob or Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob? for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I m lost between all those packages I m trying to use them with .NET Core 3.1.

I m using Azure.Cosmos and Azure.Storage.Blob, but I m unsure if I need to use the Microsoft ones.

I will be running Asp.net Core on Kubernetes container and azure function also on Kubernetes

Cosmos Db

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Cosmos/4.0.0-preview3
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/3.9.0-preview

Blob Storage

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.4.1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/11.1.4

Comment: Please edit your question and include the links to the Nuget package source.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS thank you, I have added the packages links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cosmos, the recommended package is [`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos (version 3.8)`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/3.8.0) simply because version 4 is in preview and 3.8 is the latest version generally available at the time of providing this answer. Please see this link regarding ETA on the general availability of v4 of SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1370.

For Storage, the recommended package is [`Azure.Storage.Blobs (version 12.4.1)`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.4.1) as this is the latest one at the time of providing this answer.

Comment: hello so the Azure.cosmos is the future but in previews? and the Microsoft version 3.8 is the current recommended stable?

The version 4 will be on Azure.Cosmos or the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos will continue to version 4?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ones are the older versions, for [v12 blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) you should use the non-Microsoft ones and for [v11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy) use the Microsoft ones.

It would make sense for you to refer to the above links to determine which you need to use for your case but obviously if possible use the latest version. Be aware that last time I looked v12 was problematic to use with the storage emulator which is being replaced by the Azurite emulator, which was only partially complete!